# How can I see total points per certain tag?

Tags: support, tag-score

I can't seem to find if this option is available on the profile page, so if someone knows would appreciate it if he would point it out. If it doesn't exist, then I would like to file a feature request.

Comment: Did you look at the tags tab of your activity page? Hover over the number by the tag there.

Comment: Ah, tbh, I wasn't aware of that. Surely, I was looking in the tag tab, but every time I clicked, instead of stayed long enough to just "hover" over. Thanks! Btw, if you don't mind writing the answer, I'll surely upvote and mark as correct answer - if not, I can make the answer myself. However, thanks again.

Comment: When in doubt, hover!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your activity page there is a tags tab.

This lists all tags where you have had posts on. When you hover over number to the left of a tag a tooltip tells you all the stats for it:

> [image: tags tab with tooltip when hovering on number]

Comment: Thanks, will accept asap the grace period for acceptance is over (5mins still).