# How can I see total points per certain tag on a mobile phone?

Tags: support, tags, mobile-web, tag-score

There's already a similar question where the [answer marked as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258530/364217) relies on hover the mouse on a specific location (so the question didn't consider mobile web users). Considering mobile phone have considerable popularity and [they likely don't support pointing-only events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427465/5675325), how then can one know about the tag score (to know how far one is from winning a tag badge)?

If it's not possible, then I would like to file a feature request.

Comment: Do you want to see the answer score (relevant for the tag badges) or the total question+answer score?

Comment: Hi @wimi, the relevant part for tag badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** this answer requires that you be using the [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/643262) of the SE website, which you should be using anyway. If you only see two icons (inbox and reputation) on the top right corner of the website, go all the way down and click "full site" to switch to responsive design.

As mentioned in [the answer you link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258530/643262), the total score of your **answers** with a certain tag is available in the "Tags" tab in your profile. This is the relevant score for tag badges. This information **does not require hovering**: the number to the left of each tag is your total answer score in that tag. For example, in this screenshot, I have an **answer score** of 42 in the tag "gramática", which appears to the left of the tag and also in the hover text.

[image: tag score]

The **number of posts** (questions+answers) with a certain tag appears to the right of the tab*, after the "×" sign. You can also track your **answer score** and **number of answers** for a certain tag using the tag badge tracker in the "Reputation" panel (also in the screenshot). Just click on the wheel and select the tag you are interested in.

The only information that requires hovering is your total **score in questions** with a tag. If someone is interested in this information, there is no other option than hovering or seeing the source code (html) of the served page (which is possible on mobile but takes time).

*For the sharp-eyed people who noticed that 17+1 is not equal to 19, the reason is that all the scores and number of posts reported in the profile refer only to non-community-wiki posts **except** the "number of posts" stat after the "×" sign, which also includes community-wiki posts.